# Cannot create HTTPTileDataSource with Nutiteq SDK Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, nutiteq

I have some problems with Windows phone nutiteq sdk.

```
string onlineTiles = "http://tile.tgt72.ru/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png";
var tileDataSource = new HTTPTileDataSource(1,10, onlineTiles);
```

This code raises NullReferenceException.

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an   object.
at Nutiteq.DataSources.HTTPTileDataSource.SwigDerivedClassHasMethod(String methodName, Type[] methodTypes)
at Nutiteq.DataSources.HTTPTileDataSource.SwigDirectorConnect()
at Nutiteq.DataSources.HTTPTileDataSource..ctor(Int32 minZoom, Int32 maxZoom, String baseURL)
at CityTransportWP.MapPage.ApplySourceForMap()
at CityTransportWP.MapPage.InitMap()
at CityTransportWP.MapPage..ctor()
at CityTransportWP.CityTransportWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_3_MapPage()
at CityTransportWP.CityTransportWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, this is a bug in SDK 3.1 and 3.2RC1. This is fixed in 3.2RC2 that will be released shortly (this week).

Comment: 3.2.0RC2 with this fix is published now, see https://developer.nutiteq.com/downloads